# Eureka clients in docker container

Tags: java, rest, docker, netflix-eureka

I have an eureka server and two rest services (eureka clients) running in docker containers. If the first service tries to access the second one, I get an UnknownHostException. The reason is that the services register on eureka server with the container host name which the dns server can not resolve.

I thought the solution could be setting the host name for docker containers. So I used docker with the -h flag to set the host name: 
`docker run -h project-dev.net9.mycompany.com`

But now the services can not even register on the eureka server. I get this exception:

```
 2015-11-30 12:03:42.182 ERROR 1 --- [pool-2-thread-1]    com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Can't get a response from http://project-dev.net9.mycompany.com:8761/eureka/apps/MY-SERVICE/project-dev.net9.mycompany.com
     Can't contact any eureka nodes - possibly a security group issue?

 com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:184)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:120)
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:28)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.put(WebResource.java:211)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1097)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1060)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.access$500(DiscoveryClient.java:105)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1583)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:170)
    ... 14 common frames omitted

2015-11-30 12:03:42.182 ERROR 1 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MY-SERVICE/project-dev.net9.mycompany.com - was unable to send heartbeat!

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:184)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:120)
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:28)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.put(WebResource.java:211)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1097)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1060)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.access$500(DiscoveryClient.java:105)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1583)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:170)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

The domain project-dev.net9.mycompany.com is accessible in our network and I can ping it.

I can also access the eureka dashboard under http://project-dev.net9.mycompany.com:8761/. So eureka server is running properly.

I'm grateful for any hint.

Comment: Have you tried setting `eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address` to `true`? The client will register itself with its IP address then instead of its hostname.

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address to true? The client will register itself with its IP address then instead of its hostname.

*per suggestion here: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)*